# Validation error in controller returns 401 instead of 400

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a post endpoint in my rest controller which is accessible without authentication/authorization. it is configured in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/user");
}
```

The endpoint has a validation of an input data (provided by annotation javax.validation.Valid). When I send invalid data, I receive 401 response instead of 400. This problem doesn't exist in secured endpoints, where the default spring boot 400 message is sent.

During debugging, I discovered that during handling the MethodArgumentNotValidException (which is thrown when the validation error occurs in the controller), the WebExpressionVoter is executed and returns value -1, which means 'access denied'. How can I configure my application to ignore security checks for endpoints, which are public?

I know that using ControllerAdvice for exception handling is one of the option, but is it possible to have default 400 messages?

Thanks in advance for any hints!

EDIT:

```
Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found the soulution. I don't why, but when an exception occurs, there is another POST request to this url: /error. When I added this url to my ignoring list then it started to work. So my configuration looks like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/user", "/error/**")
}
```

@Ken Chan thank you for the information about debuging filters! It was crucial.

Comment: Congratulation . So that mean your `/api/v1/user` is redirect to the `/error/**` in case of error and `/error/` is secured by spring security.....

Answer (score 1):

Using `webSecurity.ignoring()` will cause the request to that URL bypass the whole security filter chain totally . So it is interesting that `WebExpressionVoter` would still kick in for these ignored URLs.

So , I am guessing the following possibilities :

- `/api/v1/user` will be redirected to other URL which is secured.
- You are thinking `antMatchers("/api/v1/user")` will match all URLs under `/api/v1/user` such as  `/api/v1/user/1` . However, it only matches `/api/v1/user` .

To ignore all URLs under `/api/v1/user` , you should use :

```
 web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/user/**");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I checked that and I send a post request on {{host}}/api/v1/user, so I think this is not a problem. In the debug log I see sth like this: Checking match of request : AntPathRequestMatcher : '/api/v1/user'; against '/api/v1/user'. Could you tell me where is the filter which is resposible for ignoring security filters?

Comment: Interesting  , will the `/api/v1/user` will be redirect to other URL?  They are ignored at the `FilterChainProxy`. Would you please set `@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)` such that in the log ,you can see which filters are used to handle a request ?

Comment: I added filter chain to the question. No it is just a simple POST request.