# Spring boot security, enable default error handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using spring security for authentication users on my protected URLs. However, it seems that by enabling the spring-security I'm not getting the default error message from spring when the exception is being thrown. See here:

Spring security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@FieldDefaults(level = PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(DefaultPath.DEFAULT_API_PATH + "/public/**"));
    //everything else is being as authentication EP
    private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new NegatedRequestMatcher(PUBLIC_URLS);

    TokenAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    SecurityConfig(final TokenAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        super();
        this.authenticationProvider = requireNonNull(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                // this entry point handles when you request a protected page and you are not yet
                // authenticated
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS)
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable();
    }
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/register")
    ResponseEntity<String> register(@RequestBody UserRegister userRegister) {

        String email = userRegister.getEmail();
        String passwordPlain = userRegister.getPasswordPlain();

        //todo not to register same user twice
        userRepository.save(User.builder()
                .email(email)
                .password(BCrypt.hashpw(passwordPlain, BCrypt.gensalt()))
                .build());
        if (true)
        throw new IllegalStateException("A");

        return ResponseEntity.ok(login(UserLogin.builder()
                .email(email)
                .passwordPlain(passwordPlain)
                .build()));
    }
```

Response:

```
POST http://localhost:8090/api/v1/mobile/public/users/register

HTTP/1.1 401 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 09 Aug 2021 19:03:51 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive

<Response body is empty>

Response code: 401; Time: 264ms; Content length: 0 bytes
```

I know, that it has something to do with the order in which the request/response is being processed through the filters. However, would be very appreciated if someone could give me hint, how should I either modify error handling on the service/controller level or change the spring security configuration.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the expected Response Body in case the `IllegalStateException` is thrown? Do you expect "A"?

Comment: @JoãoDias It is just an example. It'd be replaced with my custom exceptions. However, the response should be something like: {
    "timestamp": "2019-01-17T16:12:45.977+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "A",
    "path": "/my-endpoint....."
} aka default spring error attr

Answer (score 2):

I found exactly the same problem here: [Validation error in controller returns 401 instead of 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484013/validation-error-in-controller-returns-401-instead-of-400)

So solution was to add .antMatchers("/error/**"); to the configuration like this

```
@Override
public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS).antMatchers("/error/**");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring you will find 4 different solutions that might suit your use case.

I would go for the 3rd one (@ControllerAdvice):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {CustomException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleCustomExceptions(Exception exception, WebRequest webRequest) {
        HttpStatus errorCode = this.resolveAnnotatedResponseStatus(exception);
        return this.handleExceptionInternal(exception, new ErrorInfo(errorCode.value(), exception.getMessage()), new HttpHeaders(), errorCode, webRequest);
    }

    private HttpStatus resolveAnnotatedResponseStatus(Exception exception) {
        ResponseStatus annotation = findMergedAnnotation(exception.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class);
        return Objects.nonNull(annotation) ? annotation.value() : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }
}
```

You would then create custom exceptions (that would extend `CustomException`) with the message that you want to include in the response body. You can also include @ResponseStatus to annotate your exceptions to define the HTTP Status to use in the response (I just noticed that @ResponseStatus also has a `reason` attribute, which may in fact be used as the response body).

There is also solution 4 (ResponseStatusException) which seems interesting but to be honest I've never tried it.

I hope this helps.